# Run Web applications with different Java versions in Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, java-8, tomcat6, java-6

I am using Tomcat 6 and in need to deploy 2 web apps , one of which will run in Java6 and the other in Java8 . Is it possible to achieve the same using a single Tomcat

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. Tomcat uses only one Java process. If you need to use different JREs, you have to use different Tomcat instances.